# Find end page in javafx web view while scrolling

Tags: javafx-2

I have loaded local html file in JavaFx2. i am scrolling the web view page. I need to get alert message when i reach the end of the page.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're in a webview, you can use [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) to do that, injecting a following code into the loaded page:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var y = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
    y -= 12;
    var maxY = document.body.scrollHeight -  window.innerHeight;
    if (y == maxY)
    {
        alert('bottom');
    }
}, 200);
```

This will check if you scrolled down to the bottom every 200 ms.
Note that the standard javascript `alert()` is not available in the current JavaFX 2.x (but is planned for version 3.0). You have to handle it yourself like that:

```
webview.getEngine().setOnAlert(new EventHandler<WebEvent<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WebEvent<String> e)
        {
            System.out.println("Alert: " + e.getData());
        }
    });
```

This should print `Alert: bottom` to standard output when scrolled to the bottom. <strike>Not tested.</strike> Tested and working.

**Note the `y -= 12`**: this is to account for if the horizontal scroll bar is visible. 12 is the standard height of the scroll bar (so you need to modify it if you're styling scroll bars with CSS). **Also, if you are not expecting to see horizontal scroll bars, you need to remove that line altogether.** For that reason I recommend manually disabling horizontal scroll bars using CSS.

Also, on a related note, for some reason if you're in fullscreen `WebView` the `maxY` is going to always be `0`. Currently there doesn't seem to be a workaround